# Gmail and mutt: msmtp error

Tags: command-line, email, mutt

```
Invalid SMTP URL: ssmtp://REDACTED@gmail.com@smtp.gmail.com:465/
```

I can use mutt to read my Gmail, but when I try to send I get the above message. When I installed `mutt` a screen came up for postfix (?) config, and I chose 'None'.

Comment: Gmail uses port 587 for smtp... And please post the relevant part of your `.muttrc`.

Comment: According to muttrc(5), mutt only supports SMTP URLs in the form `smtp[s]://...`, your `ssmtp://` will most likely not work.

Comment: @jasonwryan, gmail does support smtps (SMTP over SSL on port 465) in addition to submission (SMTP on port 587 for submission only, where STARTTLS is supported). Here, you want `smtps://REDACTED@gmail.com@smtp.gmail.com` (465 is the default port for SMTPS, like 443 is the default port for HTTPS (HTTP over SSL)).

Comment: set imap_user = "xxx.lee@gmail.com"
set imap_pass = "xxxxxx"

set smtp_url = "ssmtp://xxx.lee@gmail.com@smtp.gmail.com:465/"
set smtp_pass = "xxxxxx"
set from = "xxx.lee@gmail.com"
set realname = "Travis Lee"

set folder = "imaps://imap.gmail.com:993"
set spoolfile = "+INBOX"
set postponed="+[Gmail]/Drafts"

set header_cache=~/.mutt/cache/headers
set message_cachedir=~/.mutt/cache/bodies
set certificate_file=~/.mutt/certificates

set move = no